# Access denied error with robocopy as admin

Tags: windows-vista, robocopy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Robocopy permission denied](https://superuser.com/questions/25509/robocopy-permission-denied)

When trying to run the following command

```
robocopy d:\directory \\server\directory /S /XO /COPY:DT
```

I get an access denied error.  I am running Vista Ultimate x64, Administrator permissions, I am the owner of both directories.

I saw this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/25509/robocopy-permission-denied) and thought it was similar, but I'm getting the following error message:

```
ERROR 5 (0x00000005)(Copying file d:\blah....)
```

Is there a fix for this? If not, Is there a way to skip the errored files and just continue on to the next files?

Comment: is one of the folders a network folder?

Comment: Presumably the \\server\directory is network (in response to John T). However, perhaps that should be \\server\SHARE_NAME\directory instead?

Comment: Three points:
1. Is any file in the directory in use? (Check using Unlocker 1.8.7)
2. Is UAC on. If yes are you running the bat file with elevated permissions or no?
3. Can you first try connecting to the \\server manully & see if it requires any authorization for access.

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/25509/robocopy-permission-denied.

Answer (score 2):

Quoted from [here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-2852628.php) :

> In my case, I started out with full
>   control on both the source and
>   destination shares. The problem was
>   that Robocopy was resetting the ACL on
>   the destination share to a null value
>   (nobody has permission) before it
>   began recursing subdirectories. After
>   some quick tests, my conclusion is
>   that Robocopy does not handle
>   inherited permissions. Say you are
>   copying C:\Share1 to D:\, and
>   C:\Share1 is inheriting its
>   permissions from the C:\ root
>   directory, it actually has no explicit
>   ACL. Therefore, when you copy its ACL,
>   you are actually copying... nothing.
>   By copying an empty ACL to your
>   destination your permissions are
>   removed in the first step of the copy,
>   and all subsequent writes to the share
>   fail with Error 5.
>
> This is only a problem when you are
>   copying from a source which you are
>   accessing WITH inherited permissions
>   and a destination which you are
>   accessing WITHOUT inherited
>   permissions. If you copy C:\ (which
>   has you explicitly in its ACL), to
>   D:\, there is no issue. If this is
>   indeed your problem, you can resolve
>   it by adding yourself explicitly to
>   the source ACL with full control. When
>   the copy runs, your ACL entry is
>   duplicated to the destination, and the
>   subsequent file copies can be written.
>   You can undo your changes (on both
>   source and destination) after the copy
>   completes.
>
> If you continue to have problems
>   despite the above, you might want to
>   consider trying the /B switch, which
>   attempts to back up the file using
>   your privileges as a Backup Operator.
>   This will allow you to copy files that
>   you otherwise couldn't, for example,
>   if you are not on the ACL on your
>   destination share. Robocopy defaults
>   to attempting a restartable copy. By
>   giving up restartable copies the worst
>   case is that you lose the file
>   currently being transferred in the
>   event of a disruption. The next pass
>   will restart that file from its
>   beginning instead of partway through.
>
> Hope that helps. Here's a quote from
>   Microsoft's Robocopy doc regarding the
>   /B switch:
>
> Quote:
>
> If you copy NTFS security information
>   (ACLs) along with file data, it is
>   possible to copy files to which you
>   have read access, but not write
>   access. After such a file is copied
>   once, and the ACLs are applied, you
>   may find that to get an “Access
>   Denied” error when you try to copy the
>   file again. In this situation you
>   should use the /B or /ZB switch to
>   copy the files in Backup Mode.
>
> /B copies all files with backup
>   semantics (Backup Mode). /ZB first
>   attempts to copy files in restartable
>   mode (for greater resiliency) but if
>   that fails with an “Access Denied”
>   error it automatically retries the
>   copy using Backup Mode.