# Windows 10 - Robocopy chokes on a directory called "Recovery"?

Tags: windows-10, ntfs, robocopy

Trying to use Robocopy with the MIR switch to copy the entire contents of one disk (not networked) to a directory on another (also not networked).

The source disk is E:.

The target disk/directory is F:\20190113T135300

When the process gets to E:\Recovery Robocopy enters a loop of saying :

```
Error 5 (0x0000005) Accessing Destination Directory F:\20190113T135300\Recovery\ Access is Denied 
Waiting 30 seconds
```

I have two questions I suppose.

First when I look at the amount of left on F: it's as if no copies at all have taken place but the copy has been running for eight hours and the names of files have been scrolling up the screen. If I look for the target directory it's not visible in a new explorer windows but I have previously opened explorer windows which show the copied content as it was when I last checked (three hours ago).

Second I am running on an Administrator account which is not *the* Administrator account. When I look through Explorer for E:\Recovery I can find no sign of that directory . When I run a CMD "As Administrator" I still can't see it . How can I see E:\Recovery ? I am assuming E:\Recover has been created by Windows - is that so ?

Having read [Robocopy permission denied](https://superuser.com/questions/25509/robocopy-permission-denied) I'm tempted to restart with the /B flag but as I can't even see the E:\Recovery directory I'm wondering what else I can't see that might trip me over during the restarted process

---

**What I've done so far**

In an attempt to get things back on Track I gave "Full Control" to all "Authorised Users" . That hasn't made any difference to ROBOCOPY saying that access is denied.

I've also looked at these answers : [Access denied error with robocopy as admin](https://superuser.com/questions/48303/access-denied-error-with-robocopy-as-admin) , [Robocopy permission denied](https://superuser.com/questions/25509/robocopy-permission-denied) .

---

**EDIT 1** : I don't explicitly wish to copy E:\Recovery - I just want to copy everything on the E drive. Until I hit this problem I was unaware the E:\Recovery directory existed.

Comment: recovery is a protected partition. Why are you trying to copy files off of it?

Comment: @Moab - thanks for your response, I'm about to edit the question to answer your question.

Comment: See this to exclude the folder from copy....https://pureinfotech.com/exclude-files-folders-robocopy-windows-10/#exclude_folder_robocopy