# Robocopy - NTFS Access is Denied

Tags: command-line, ntfs, network-shares, windows-server-2012, robocopy

I am trying to backup a disk from one share to another using robocopy with the following command:

```
robocopy \\servername\E$ \\servername\F$\Copy /E /ZB /copyall /r:5 /w:30 /dcopy:T /log:"C:\Temp\log.log" /v /fp /tee /eta
```

However whenever I try to execute the command (with Admin privileges), I get the following error:

```
ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Copying NTFS Security to Destination Directory \\servername\F$\Copy
Access is Denied.
```

Now the NTFS permissions for the user logged in has **full control**, as well as the Administrator account on both shares (E and F). I am running the command from a *Windows 2012* server and pointing the source/destination to a *Windows 2003* server *(which I cannot run the following robocopy command as its an older version)*. The share is fully accessible from the W2012 server, therefore this should not be the problem.

I have already looked at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/25509/robocopy-permission-denied) which has not solved my issue as I already have the `/ZB` parameter.

Comment: 99.999% you have just tried but i cannot understand if you have done manually the simple copy of just one file to `\\servername\F$\Copy` to verify that it is possible to write there. Just to transform that `should not` in `with high probability is not ` :)

Comment: Interestingly I can copy a file on the 2003 server (where the drives/shares are) from E to F/Copy. But I cannot do it from the 2012 server using the share in file explorer (\\servername\E$ and \\servername\F$\Copy? Not sure why this is, as I am logged in as the same user. Maybes its the share permissions, although I cannot edit because it says `This has been shared for administrative purposes. The permissions cannot be set.` (Even though I am an admin). @Hastur

Comment: So sadly that `should not` became `it seems it is`. :-) What do you mean with you are logged with the same user? The same couple `username/password` on the W2003? BTW to read so the error message it seems it's not enough a common user you should run the command as  `the` administrator (the user admin or administrator of the W2003 and not `a` privileged user of W2012). I suppose you will receive the same error even if you simply try to copy a file from W2012 to `\\servernameW2013\F$\Copy`.

Comment: The same domain admin user (roaming profile). I cannot execute the command from the W2003 server because it has an outdated version of robocopy. Oddly enough, I `can copy files from E: to F:\Copy on the W2003`, but I **cannot on the W2012**. (just with write click, copy and paste) @Hastur

Comment: Odd enough. :) I suppose even `E` is on the W2003 server. Can you copy from a local file (`C:\`) on W2012 to the remote directory `\\servernameW2012\F$\Copy`? If even this is not possible it's definitively a problem of permissions on the W2003 server, and over there you have to investigate and solve.

Comment: Nope I cannot do that either. It must be the share permissions, even though I cannot access them. Strange? @Hastur

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30262/discussion-between-hastur-and-jonathan-davies).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **robocopy command was perfect**. It turns out that the F:\ drive which is located at nas3, does **not like multiple connections** at once.

Therefore the solution was too:

1. iSCSI **unmount** F:\ on the W2003 machine
2. iSCSI **mount** F:\ on the W2012

The command ran perfectly after the changes.